# Vb net Regex retrieve data up to specific keyword or end of string

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have several string like

```
    kw_CS_TABLE__FC29-001::details=MIN_CAT::title=xxxx
    kw_CS_TABLE__FC29-002::details=CAT to NSE
    kw_CS_TABLE__FC29-003::details=HAZMIN::
```

I want to retrieve only the details string (MIN_CAT, CAT to NSE, HAZMIN).
I use the regex `(?<=::details=)(.*)(?=::)`, it looks fine for the first and 3rd case. But it fails for the second case.
I am struggle with the recognition of the end of the string. I use the `|$` command, but in this case, I retrieve all the sentence up to the end of the file.
    (?<=::details=)(.*)(?=::|$)

`kw_CS_TABLE__FC29-001::details=MIN_CAT::title=xxxx` 
returns `> MIN_CAT::title=xxxx`

I have a lots of difficulties to understand the regex concepts, especially because I use it only for some specific case. I read several tutorials and posts, but nothing solve my problem.

Thanks

Comment: Use `(?<=::details=).*?(?=::|$)`. Demo: https://regex101.com/r/crm3fy/1

Comment: I was not so far... Thanks it's working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Without regex

```vb
Private Function GetDetailsFrom(line As String) As String
    Return  line.Split({"::"}, StringSplitOptions.None).
        Where(Function(item) item.StartsWith("details")).
        Select(Function(detail) detail.Split({"="c}).LastOrDefault()).
        FirstOrDefault()
End Function
```

Usage

```
Dim lines As String() = 
{
    "kw_CS_TABLE__FC29-001::details=MIN_CAT::title=xxxx",
    "kw_CS_TABLE__FC29-002::details=CAT to NSE",
    "kw_CS_TABLE__FC29-003::details=HAZMIN::"
}

Dim details = lines.Select(AddressOf GetDetailsFrom)

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, details))
' MIN_CAT
' CAT to NSE
' HAZMIN
```

Comment: I was ready to implement something like this. But as I several request like this do with different kind of string, I wanted to use regex to simplify the number of methods in my code. Thanks for the proposal.